# How to execute multiple functions stored in a variable bash

Tags: bash

Hello so I need some help, I am looking for a way to execute multiple functions stored in a variable. I am able to execute one function stored in a variable but not multiple please help.

This is the code that I have, it's something small I am trying to create for automation purposes.

```
PS3=$'\n'$'\e[95m'"Option: "$'\033[0m'
options=("All" "Specific")

echo -e "\n Would you want to execute All the functions or Specific  ones?"
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
  case $opt in
  "Specific")
    echo " "
    typeset -f | awk '/ \(\) $/ && !/^main / {print $1}' | awk '!/err/'
    echo ""
    read -p $'\e[0;33m Enter the function names you want to execute on the boxes (\e[1;34m eg: add_user update_upgrade ... \e[0;33m) : \033[0m' func
    functions=$(echo "$func" | tr ' ' '\n')
    echo -e "\n$functions\n"
    break
    ;;
  "All")
    typeset -f | awk '/ \(\) $/ && !/^main / {print $1}' | awk '!/err/'
    echo " "
    break
    ;;
  *)
    echo -e "\t\tKindly choose between option 1 and 2."
  esac
done
```

Then I execute the function this way;

```
$functions
```

But it only executes the first function, is there a way I can manage to execute multiple function names stored in the variable `$func`

Comment: try `eval "$functions"`

Comment: Ohhhh it worked.... how comes damn it was as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

As @pynexj suggested to try and using `eval "$functions"` worked, So we are good to go.